# How to have the same text style as the source image when performing translation of text on an Image? Eg. Google Translate 'Image'

Tags: android, firebase, image-processing, translation

I am making an Android Application like Google Translate but only for images.
I have detected the text using Firebase Text Recognition and performed translation using the Amazon Translate. The next challenge is to merge the translated text onto the source image as if it is a part of the image, google translate does it and I want to do the same.

Can anyone help me on how to get the same results as shown in the image below?

[image: Google Translate: Text from Image Transaltion]

Comment: This is an incredibly broad topic, with too many steps to cover in one Stack Overflow questions. But to to translate the text you can for example use [Google Cloud's Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/).

Comment: I have used the Amazon Translate service for the translation, and also explored GCT API. But both only help in translation. I am a beginner, may you please walk me through the steps on how to perform the style merger of the text after translation as shown in the picture?